# Different objects with the same name using a loop

Tags: java, android

Why is the following correct and working? I thought each object should have a different name:

```
LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootView);


int i = 0;
while (i<5) {
    TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
    wordView.setText(words.get(i));
    rootView.addView(wordView);

    i++;
}
```

However, if I tried to do it without loop:

```
TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
wordView.setText(words.get(0));
rootView.addView(wordView);

TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
wordView.setText(words.get(1));
rootView.addView(wordView);
```

It's not allowed, so how does it work exactly in java - that a loop creates different objects with the same name?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a basic concept called variable scope. Objects also don't have names.

Comment: I do not see two objects with the same name in the first snippet.  Is it just me?

Comment: ***There are no "different objects with the same name"*** in the first snippet of the question.  Am I the only one who sees this?

Comment: @MikeNakis The OP is referring to declaring `TextView wordView` five times, once each time through the loop.

Comment: @MikeM. wow.  I am astounded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to understand is the **block scope for a local variable** i.e., **Each local variable scope is limited to the block** and try the following code and it will work:

```
{//1st block started
   TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
   wordView.setText(words.get(0));
   rootView.addView(wordView);
  //1st block wordView scope ends here
}//1st block ended

{//2nd block started
   TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
   wordView.setText(words.get(1));
   rootView.addView(wordView);
    //2nd block wordView scope ends here
}//2nd block ended
```

Also, **coming to `while` loop, you can think of it like 5 blocks** like above (i.e., each block getting executed for each iteration).

You can refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4) from JLS how the local variable scope works:

> Every local variable declaration statement is immediately contained by
>   a block. Local variable declaration statements may be intermixed
>   freely with other kinds of statements in the block.

---

Also, just one correction on your phrase "each object should have a different name", this should be like "each reference variable should have a different name" to make more sense (because objects are assigned to and pointed by reference variables).

Comment: Thank you! I do understand the concept of scope, and thank you for the correction about each reference variable should have a different name,
So, since all of the objects have the same reference name in this case, I won't be able to access any specific one later? I mean, this loop is only meant to create those Views on the screen and I will not be able to "choose" any specific one to work on later?

Answer (score -1):

This should guide you to enable you get different output name base on the arrays
 and if you are looking at same name loop

```html
public static void main(String[] args) {
String option1 = "o1v1,o1v2,o1v3";
String option2 = "o2v1,o2v2,o2v3";
String option3 = "o3v1,o3v2,o3v3";
ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] options1 = option1.split(",");
String[] options2 = option2.split(",");
String[] options3 = option3.split(",");

for(int i=0; i<options1.length; i++){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(options1[i]);
    sb.append(options2[i]);
    sb.append(options3[i]);
    output.add(sb.toString());


}

System.out.println(output);

}
```

Though this will output with a comma

Comment: how does this answer the question?  Actually no, let me put it differently: how is this even remotely related to the question?  Counting: 10... 9... 8...

Comment: basically i just fely you could try a for loop instead of while loop. Dont really have a good clip of the specific issue but i think a for loop will do the job